# How to hide the output comming from an inherited content element?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

On a sub page I am inheriting multiple content elements from a parent page.  Now I need to hide one of them, while keeping the rest untouched.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use TypoScript to hide the output from the respective content element or plugin.

Identify the responsible element for the output using TYPO3 ADMIN PANEL.

Create a new template for the page (List view) and add the necessary configuration in the Setup field.

Below is an example:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = YOURPAGEID]
    plugin.tx_exampleplugin >
[global]
```

Comment: Note that this approach is bound to get hairy. You'll soon find yourself unable to determine whats going on if your Backend doesn't reflect the actual content elements displayed. If I find myself in such situations, I just overwrite the elements in the column on the subpage. TYPO3 has a reference content element which you can point to the elements you want to inherit from the parent page.

Comment: If you could add a more detailed answer it would be great.